# javascript - Trigger "enter" on 3rd party websites input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a javascript/jquery script in the Chrome developer console of a 3rd party website. The website has an input field, with no submit button and I am trying to add text to that input field, and then press enter once it has been written.

The problem is, the typical javascript/jquery `trigger` event doesn't seem to work. This is my code:

```
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.keyCode = 13;
    var input = $('input.my_email');
    input.val("myemail@gmail.com");

    setTimeout(function() {
        input.trigger(e);
    }, 1000);
```

This code above **doesn't** work. Is there any alternative to "entering" an input field? I added the `setTimeout` for no particular reason. I thought it might help but it didn't.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just programmatically submit the form (if it is a form)? IIRC jQuery events are not real browser events.

Comment: «of a 3rd party website» hewmm... Is it what I think? Scripting on one page for action on ANOTHER PAGE (another opened tab) ?

Comment: If you inspect the element in dev tools you will be able to edit the HTML, add a your email address, and a submit button. Reason why you need to do it with jQuery?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 There is a form attached but I've tried `$('.theform').submit()` but it doesn't submit. It just refreshes the page it seems...

Comment: @Katie If you really want to dispatch a native `keypress` event, check out [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks for the suggestion.. could you be more specific about how it could help?

Comment: @Katie You said `.submit()` does not work so I assume the form is set up to programmatically submit the form data. You also said pressing the actual "enter" key works. So instead of dispatching fake jQuery events, you should dispatch real events: [Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5bbupouy/)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks for the example. I tried what you suggested and it just returns `true`.. Any idea why perhaps?

Comment: @Katie Without knowing how the page is doing its thing, I really don't know what you can do to make it work. You will have to figure it out by yourself.